# Getting an arch in animation

Tags: animation

I did a google search but I can't seem to find anything relevant. I basically want to have an animation between two points but instead of the object traveling on a straight path I want it to go in more of an arch. I tried inserting keyframes and doing it manually but this seems very error prone and the animation becomes to jagged.

Is there a tool that does something similar to this?

[image: Arch between two positions]

Comment: Keyframing what you have there isn't as hard as it looks-- what you basically have is linear motion in X and curved (= t^2) motion in Z.  Same as any falling body.  But as a more general solution, you could look into the follow path constraint, in order to animate an object along a curve.

Comment: yes, the Follow Path constraint, you will find a lot of tutorials on this topic on Youtube

Comment: @Nathan yeah I guess in this case it wouldn't be too much work to get it right, but in more complex situations where the archs are not controlled by gravity it will probably get messy.

Comment: I will definitely look into follow path constraints!